# Date axis in heatmap seaborn

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

A little info: I'm very new to programming and this is a small part of the my first script. The goal of this particular segment is to display a seaborn heatmap with vertical depth on y-axis, time on x-axis and intensity of a scientific measurement as the heat function.

I'd like to apologize if this has been answered elsewhere, but my searching abilities must have failed me.

```
sns.set()
nametag = 'Well_4_all_depths_capf'
Dp = D[D.well == 'well4']
print(Dp.date)


heat = Dp.pivot("depth",  "date", "capf")
### depth, date and capf are all columns of a pandas dataframe 

plt.title(nametag)

sns.heatmap(heat,  linewidths=.25)

plt.savefig('%s%s.png' % (pathheatcapf, nametag), dpi = 600)
```

this is the what prints from the ' print(Dp.date) '
so I'm pretty sure the formatting from the dataframe is in the format I want, particularly Year, day, month.

```
0    2016-08-09
1    2016-08-09
2    2016-08-09
3    2016-08-09
4    2016-08-09
5    2016-08-09
6    2016-08-09
         ...
```

But, when I run it the date axis always prints with blank times (00:00 etc) that I don't want.
Is there a way to remove these from the date axis?

Is the problem that in a cell above I used this function to scan the file name and make a column with the date??? Is it wrong to use datetime instead of just a date function?

```
D['date']=pd.to_datetime(['%s-%s-%s' %(f[0:4],f[4:6],f[6:8]) for f in             
D['filename']])
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You have to use strftime function for your date series of dataframe to plot xtick labels correctly:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

dates = [datetime.today() - timedelta(days=x * random.getrandbits(1)) for x in xrange(25)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'depth': [0.1,0.05, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001],\
 'date': dates,\
 'value': [-4.1808639999999997, -9.1753490000000006, -11.408113999999999, -10.50245, -8.0274750000000008, -0.72260200000000008, -6.9963940000000004, -10.536339999999999, -9.5440649999999998, -7.1964070000000007, -0.39225599999999999, -6.6216390000000001, -9.5518009999999993, -9.2924690000000005, -6.7605589999999998, -0.65214700000000003, -6.8852289999999989, -9.4557760000000002, -8.9364629999999998, -6.4736289999999999, -0.96481800000000006, -6.051482, -9.7846860000000007, -8.5710630000000005, -6.1461209999999999]})
pivot = df.pivot(index='depth', columns='date', values='value')

sns.set()
ax = sns.heatmap(pivot)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
plt.xticks(rotation=-90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This now gives `ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (13), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (25).`, so not sure it's quite right...

Comment: @ChrisWithers "Note that it is important to set both, the tick locations (set_xticks) as well as the tick labels (set_xticklabels), otherwise they would become out of sync." from [matplotlib doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-annotated-heatmap-py)

Comment: @BennyJobigan - maybe edit the answer to take this into account and make it work?

Answer (score 4):

Example with standard heatmap datetime labels

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dates = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2020-12-01')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(len(dates), 4)), index=dates)

sns.heatmap(df)
```

[image: standard_heatmap]

We can create some helper classes/functions to get to some better looking labels and placement. `AxTransformer` enables conversion from data coordinates to tick locations, `set_date_ticks` allows custom date ranges to be applied to plots.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections.abc import Iterable
from sklearn import linear_model

class AxTransformer:
    def __init__(self, datetime_vals=False):
        self.datetime_vals = datetime_vals
        self.lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        
        return
    
    def process_tick_vals(self, tick_vals):
        if not isinstance(tick_vals, Iterable) or isinstance(tick_vals, str):
            tick_vals = [tick_vals]
            
        if self.datetime_vals == True:
            tick_vals = pd.to_datetime(tick_vals).astype(int).values
            
        tick_vals = np.array(tick_vals)
            
        return tick_vals
    
    def fit(self, ax, axis='x'):
        axis = getattr(ax, f'get_{axis}axis')()
        
        tick_locs = axis.get_ticklocs()
        tick_vals = self.process_tick_vals([label._text for label in axis.get_ticklabels()])
        
        self.lr.fit(tick_vals.reshape(-1, 1), tick_locs)
        
        return
    
    def transform(self, tick_vals):        
        tick_vals = self.process_tick_vals(tick_vals)
        tick_locs = self.lr.predict(np.array(tick_vals).reshape(-1, 1))
        
        return tick_locs
    
def set_date_ticks(ax, start_date, end_date, axis='y', date_format='%Y-%m-%d', **date_range_kwargs):
    dt_rng = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, **date_range_kwargs)

    ax_transformer = AxTransformer(datetime_vals=True)
    ax_transformer.fit(ax, axis=axis)
    
    getattr(ax, f'set_{axis}ticks')(ax_transformer.transform(dt_rng))
    getattr(ax, f'set_{axis}ticklabels')(dt_rng.strftime(date_format))

    ax.tick_params(axis=axis, which='both', bottom=True, top=False, labelbottom=True)
    
    return ax
```

These provide us a lot of flexibility, e.g.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=150)

sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax)

set_date_ticks(ax, '2019-01-01', '2020-12-01', freq='3MS')
```

[image: cleaned_heatmap_date_labels]

or if you really want to get weird you can do stuff like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=150)

sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax)

set_date_ticks(ax, '2019-06-01', '2020-06-01', freq='2MS', date_format='%b `%y')
```

[image: weird_heatmap_date_labels]

For your specific example you'll have to pass `axis='x'` to `set_date_ticks`

Comment: `tick_vals = pd.to_datetime(tick_vals).astype(int).values` causes a `FutureWarning: The behavior of .astype from datetime64[ns] to int32 is deprecated.` Replace with `tick_vals = pd.to_datetime(tick_vals).astype("int64").values`.

Answer (score 1):

- First, the `'date'` column must be converted to a `datetime dtype` with `pandas.to_datetime`
- If the desired result is to only have the dates (without time), then the easiest solution is to use the [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) to extract the `.date` component. Alternative, use [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to set a specific string format.

  - [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)
  - `df.date.dt.strftime('%H:%M')` would extract hours and minutes into a string like `'14:29'`
  - In the example below, the extracted date is assigned to the same column, but the value can also be assigned as a new column.
- `pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table` is used to aggregate a function if there are multiple values in a column for each `index`, `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` should be used if there is only a single value.

  - This is better than `.groupby` because the dataframe is correctly shaped to be easily plotted.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# create sample data
dates = [f'2016-08-{d}T00:00:00.000000000' for d in range(9, 26, 2)] + ['2016-09-09T00:00:00.000000000']
depths = np.arange(1.25, 5.80, 0.25)
np.random.seed(365)
p1 = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(10), size=1)[0]  # random probabilities for random.choice
p2 = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(19), size=1)[0]  # random probabilities for random.choice
data = {'date': np.random.choice(dates, size=1000, p=p1), 'depth': np.random.choice(depths, size=1000, p=p2), 'capf': np.random.normal(0.3, 0.05, size=1000)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head())
                            date  depth      capf
0  2016-08-19T00:00:00.000000000   4.75  0.339233
1  2016-08-19T00:00:00.000000000   3.00  0.370395
2  2016-08-21T00:00:00.000000000   5.75  0.332895
3  2016-08-23T00:00:00.000000000   1.75  0.237543
4  2016-08-23T00:00:00.000000000   5.75  0.272067

# make sure the date column is converted to a datetime dtype
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# extract only the date component of the date column
df.date = df.date.dt.date

# reshape the data for heatmap; if there's no need to aggregate a function, then use .pivot(...)
dfp = df.pivot_table(index='depth', columns='date', values='capf', aggfunc='mean')

# display(dfp.head())
date   2016-08-09  2016-08-11  2016-08-13  2016-08-15  2016-08-17  2016-08-19  2016-08-21  2016-08-23  2016-08-25  2016-09-09
depth                                                                                                                        
1.50     0.334661         NaN         NaN    0.302670    0.314186    0.325257    0.313645    0.263135         NaN         NaN
1.75     0.305488    0.303005    0.410124    0.299095    0.313899    0.280732    0.275758    0.260641         NaN    0.318099
2.00     0.322312    0.274105         NaN    0.319606    0.268984    0.368449    0.311517    0.309923         NaN    0.306162
2.25     0.289959    0.315081         NaN    0.302202    0.306286    0.339809    0.292546    0.314225    0.263875         NaN
2.50     0.314227    0.296968         NaN    0.312705    0.333797    0.299556    0.327187    0.326958         NaN         NaN

# plot
sns.heatmap(dfp, cmap='GnBu')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest thing to do for me is to just get the ticks, reformat them, and then put them back. This avoids the need to figure out the number and location of the ticks, because matplotlib already has done that. You just substitute the text. (see note below)

```py
def format_date_ticks(old_ticks:list[plt.Text])->list[str]:
    text = [l.get_text() for l in old_ticks] # plt.Text to str
    return pd.to_datetime(text).date # str to datetime, then format as desired

# ...

new_ticks = format_date_ticks(ax.get_xticklabels()) # get and transform old ticks
ax.set_xticklabels(new_ticks) # replace the old with new
```

Note: per comments on another answer:

> This now gives ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (13), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (25)., so not sure it's quite right...
>
> > "Note that it is important to set both, the tick locations (set_xticks) as well as the tick labels (set_xticklabels), otherwise they would become out of sync." from matplotlib doc

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem, but the date was the index. I've just converted the date to string (pandas 1.0) before plotting and it worked for me.

```py
heat['date'] = heat.date.astype('string')
```