# Seaborn heatmap, change x-axis to Dateformatter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a 2D data and plotted it in heatmap like this [(example heatmap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MN9J.png).  The x-axis is currently *matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter* and I would like to change it to *matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter* and show only year.

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
ax = sns.heatmap(df[::4][['Total','Professionals']].transpose())
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y'))
plt.show()
```

However when I uncomment the third line I get the following error.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    305                 pass
    306             else:
--> 307                 return printer(obj)
    308             # Finally look for special method names
    309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    225 
    226     if 'png' in formats:
--> 227         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    228     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    229         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    117 
    118     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 119     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    120     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    121     if fmt == 'svg':

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2178                     orientation=orientation,
   2179                     dryrun=True,
-> 2180                     **kwargs)
   2181                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2182                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    525 
    526     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 527         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    528         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    529         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    472 
    473         try:
--> 474             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    475         finally:
    476             RendererAgg.lock.release()

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1157         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1158         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1159             func(*args)
   1160 
   1161         renderer.close_group('figure')

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2317 
   2318         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2319             a.draw(renderer)
   2320 
   2321         renderer.close_group('axes')

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1106         renderer.open_group(__name__)
   1107 
-> 1108         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1109         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1110                                                                 renderer)

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
    949 
    950         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 951         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    952         if self._smart_bounds:
    953             # handle inverted limits

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    949 
    950         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 951         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    952         if self._smart_bounds:
    953             # handle inverted limits

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in iter_ticks(self)
    896         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)
    897         majorLabels = [self.major.formatter(val, i)
--> 898                        for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs)]
    899 
    900         minorLocs = self.minor.locator()

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    896         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)
    897         majorLabels = [self.major.formatter(val, i)
--> 898                        for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs)]
    899 
    900         minorLocs = self.minor.locator()

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in __call__(self, x, pos)
    482                              'you have not informed the axis that it is '
    483                              'plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()')
--> 484         dt = num2date(x, self.tz)
    485         return self.strftime(dt, self.fmt)
    486 

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in num2date(x, tz)
    417         tz = _get_rc_timezone()
    418     if not cbook.iterable(x):
--> 419         return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    420     else:
    421         x = np.asarray(x)

C:\Users\Chatdanai Lumdee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    269 
    270     ix = int(x)
--> 271     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
    272 
    273     remainder = float(x) - ix

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

---

Does anyone know what should I do to circumvent this? I tried reformatting the x-axis data using e.g. date2num first before plot, but still get the same error when trying to reformat the axis.

Comment: Look for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41258987/2666859 It may help you.

Comment: Thank you! I somehow got what I looked for :)