# How to choose date frequency and day of display with Seaborn Heatmap

Tags: dataframe, date, plot, seaborn, heatmap

I have a DataFrame with several columns and date as index. I use `sns.heatmap` to plot it, with the date on the y-axis. I would like to force the ticks to display the 1st of October of every year only. I used the solution given by @Ayrton Bourn on [Date axis in heatmap seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925458/date-axis-in-heatmap-seaborn), which allows me to change the frequency of ticks but not at which day to display the date.
His method is the only one that allows me to choose the frequency of y-ticks so far. I tried using `mdates.YearLocator()` or `set_major_locator` without success.

With the code below, do you have any suggestion that would allow me to choose the frequency of date ticks (every year) and the day displayed (every '200x-10-01' for example) ?

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections.abc import Iterable
from sklearn import linear_model

class AxTransformer:
    def __init__(self, datetime_vals=False):
        self.datetime_vals = datetime_vals
        self.lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        
        return
    
    def process_tick_vals(self, tick_vals):
        if not isinstance(tick_vals, Iterable) or isinstance(tick_vals, str):
            tick_vals = [tick_vals]
            
        if self.datetime_vals == True:
            tick_vals = pd.to_datetime(tick_vals).astype(int).values
            
        tick_vals = np.array(tick_vals)
            
        return tick_vals
    
    def fit(self, ax, axis='x'):
        axis = getattr(ax, f'get_{axis}axis')()
        
        tick_locs = axis.get_ticklocs()
        tick_vals = self.process_tick_vals([label._text for label in axis.get_ticklabels()])
        
        self.lr.fit(tick_vals.reshape(-1, 1), tick_locs)
        
        return
    
    def transform(self, tick_vals):        
        tick_vals = self.process_tick_vals(tick_vals)
        tick_locs = self.lr.predict(np.array(tick_vals).reshape(-1, 1))
        
        return tick_locs
    
def set_date_ticks(ax, start_date, end_date, axis='y', date_format='%Y-%m-%d', **date_range_kwargs):
    dt_rng = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, **date_range_kwargs)

    ax_transformer = AxTransformer(datetime_vals=True)
    ax_transformer.fit(ax, axis=axis)
    
    getattr(ax, f'set_{axis}ticks')(ax_transformer.transform(dt_rng))
    getattr(ax, f'set_{axis}ticklabels')(dt_rng.strftime(date_format))

    ax.tick_params(axis=axis, which='both', bottom=True, top=False, labelbottom=True)
    
    return ax




base = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
arr = np.array([base + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(366*3)])


val = np.random.rand(len(arr),3)
df = pd.DataFrame(val, index = arr)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))

ax = sns.heatmap(df, ax = ax)
set_date_ticks(ax, '2000-01-01', '2003-12-01', freq='1Y')
ax.format_ydata = mdates.DateFormatter('% Y')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by looking into the Kwargs.
To choose the dates displayed, the only thing to change resides in "freq =" (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) the detailed list of frequencies). In my case, in order to display yearly 1st of Octobers, I just have to change the start date to be a first of October, and the frequency to specify that I want the ticks to be at the beginning of every 12th month (the end date does not matter):

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))

ax = sns.heatmap(df, ax = ax)
set_date_ticks(ax, '2000-10-01', '2004-10-01', freq='12MS')
ax.format_ydata = mdates.DateFormatter('% Y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Glad you found this useful and managed to track down the issue!